# Example of smart contract action that itself executes a transaction

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, action

Can anyone point me to example code for writing a smart contract that calls actions on other smart contracts? The general method of doing this is documented [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Smart-Contract#communication-model-and-execution-flow) but example code is not provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this example of delegate bandwith, it executes the `transfer` action from the `eosio.token` contract using the `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER` to buy ram:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/dacc1b09d2c10cc3ca4cea7821c04ea2a47487fe/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L147

This is the code:

```
if( payer != N(eosio) ) {
   INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(eosio::token, transfer)( N(eosio.token), {payer,N(active)},
                                                 { payer, N(eosio), quant, std::string("buy ram") } );
}
```